# Get nearest intersection using HERE Maps APIs

Tags: here-api

I want to measure the distance to the next intersection/traffic light based on a gps location(s).
I DON’T have a route (i.e. no destination point) but I can get gps locations every second (while on the move).
Is it possible to get the information using HERE APIs?
I understand that there is no direct way (specific api) to do it, but I would appreciate any idea that will fulfill my needs.

The general idea that I came up with was getting at least 2 gps points to understand the direction, then getting link_id for current location and try to get the next links in same direction/road and find if any of them are intersections...

I didn’t find a way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct API for this however there is an idea that you have to crawl along the link into the direction determined like you outlined (or better by sending the last few GPS points to our Route Matcher (aka RME)) until you reach an intersection.

And this can be achieved with a concept of "**electronic horizon**" in SDK. It takes your current road link and driving direction and then crawls forward over the upcoming links until an intersection comes (or even beyond taking the most probable choice). mobile SDK has this "electronic horizon" feature.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/electronic-horizon.html

Comment: if I use RME, and get the probable route link list (https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html), how can I know from this list that I reached an intersection? is there any attribute that gives me this information?